# Drop Folder on App: Sort Contents: Make MOV

Tags: applescript

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

**Item 1. Drop folder that contains multiple image sequences onto applet**.

```
firstImageSeq0001.png
firstImageSeq0002.png
firstImageSeq0003.png
secondImageSeq0001.png
secondImageSeq0002.png
secondImageSeq0003.png
thirdImageSeq0001.png
thirdImageSeq0002.png
thirdImageSeq0001.png
```

**Item 2. Get each group of sequences in the folder and make into a quicktime mov**

The script I have currently allows me to drop a the folder on the applet and then creates a movie with the first set of images. How do I get it to continue to the next set of images?

```
on open collection

    tell application "Finder" to set theSequence to first item of folder collection as alias

    tell application "QuickTime Player 7"
        activate
        open image sequence theSequence frames per second 30

        set nameSequence to (theSequence as string) & ".mov"

        tell document 1
            with timeout of 500 seconds
                save self contained in nameSequence
            end timeout

        end tell
    end tell

end open
```

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is to keep working on first item, but once processed, delete all file with same root name and run again. the script bellow does this.

You must define lastDigitsCount according to your file names. For instance with FirstimageSeq0001.png, lastDigitsCount should be at least 8 which means that '0001.png' is excluded from rootname ofthe sequence.

```
set lastDigitsCount to 8 -- number of chars from the right which contain extension and counters
set myFolder to "imac27:Users:my_user:Desktop:test:"


repeat
tell application "Finder"
    if ((count items of folder (myFolder as alias)) = 0) then return
    set theSequence to first item of folder myFolder as alias
    set RootName to name of theSequence
    set RootName to text 1 thru ((length of RootName) - lastDigitsCount) of RootName
end tell

-- make your quicktime routine here
tell application "QuickTime Player 7"
    activate
    open image sequence theSequence frames per second 30
    set nameSequence to (theSequence as string) & ".mov"
    tell document 1
        with timeout of 500 seconds
            save self contained in nameSequence
        end timeout
    end tell
end tell

-- delete all files with same rootname
tell application "Finder"
    set myPNG to every item of folder (myFolder as alias) whose name contains RootName
    delete myPNG
end tell
end repeat
```

Comment: I think this works except that it deletes all the files including the new quicktime files. How would I exclude the new mov files?

Comment: sorry, please change the line just before the delete to exclude file with extension "mov" : set myPNG to every item of folder (myFolder as alias) whose ((name extension is not "mov") and name contains RootName)

Answer (score 0):

I have various routines for this. Here's the pseudo-code. If I have time, I'll add more concrete stuff (unless you find this a good enough jumping point):
("basename" here means the text of the file name before the number)

```
for every file:

get the basename --(this would be a call to a subroutine ["handler" in AS parlance])
if first run, do movie, & don't
 check for basename existing already
 [else, do check for existing basename]
if it doesn't exist (within list of basenames),
 do movie
```